# fatal error: cstddef: No such file or directory #include <cstddef>

Tags: rhel, rpmbuild, finalcut

Help please
I am assembling the rpm package of the final cut program
https://github.com/gansm/finalcut

When assembling, I get an error

```
In the file included from /usr/src/tmp/finalcut-buildroot/usr/include/final/fc.h:30:
/usr/src/tmp/finalcut-buildroot/usr/include/final/f, type s.h:27:10: fatal error: cstddef: There is no such file or directory #include <cstddef>
```

All dependencies are connected

My spec

```
BuildRequires: gcc-c++
BuildRequires: libstdc++-devel 
BuildRequires: automake 
BuildRequires: autoconf
BuildRequires: autoconf-archive
BuildRequires: libtool
BuildRequires: pkg-config glib2
BuildRequires: glib2-devel libtinfo-devel libncurses-devel
BuildRequires: libgpm-devel make etersoft-build-utils
Requires: libfinal = %{version}-%{release}
```

Connected all possible dependencies of new versions
I put the cstddef file directly into the project, but nothing helps
When building linux, it doesn't seem to see cstddef, although it is there, I checked

Comment: Can you provide the commands you were using and what OS you were building on? Additionally what compiler? `cstddef` should be in `libstdc++-devel` - is that package corrupt?